# MKPointAnnotation how to hide marker image

Tags: swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a `MKPointAnnotation` that I have setup and it displays where I would like it to however it comes with the default big red pin icon over the dot and I would like to hide that image and display nothing instead. I've tried working with the section I have commented below with "*****" and what I thought might work is setting `view.image=nil` and this did not change anything and I also tried `view.frame.size=CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)` which had no effect. Any other suggestions for how to accomplish this?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

      let annotation = annotation

      let identifier = "marker"
      var view: MKMarkerAnnotationView


      if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
        as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
        dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
        view = dequeuedView
      } else {
        //************************
        view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.frame.size=CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)



      }
      return view
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This was actually easier to solve than I was expecting, all I needed to do was set the `markerTintColor` to a color with alpha of 0.

```
view.markerTintColor=UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0,alpha:0.5).withAlphaComponent(0)
```

is what solved it for me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the apple documentation on the subject:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_annotations/annotating_a_map_with_custom_data

They seem to recommend coding a custom Annotation as seen:

```
class SanFranciscoAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

// This property must be key-value observable, which the `@objc dynamic` attributes provide.
@objc dynamic var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.779_379, longitude: -122.418_433)

// Required if you set the annotation view's `canShowCallout` property to `true`
var title: String? = NSLocalizedString("SAN_FRANCISCO_TITLE", comment: "SF annotation")

// This property defined by `MKAnnotation` is not required.
var subtitle: String? = NSLocalizedString("SAN_FRANCISCO_SUBTITLE", comment: "SF annotation") }
```

You can try creating a custom annotation in this way with a clear color or with a size of (0,0). Assign your view to the custom annotation you code.

```
var view: SanFranciscoAnnotation
```

If this doesn't work, I will dig up some old code from an app I wrote with custom annotations and share that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I started with this and after playing around with it I actually ended up finding a much simpler solution. all I actually needed to do was set `markerTintColor` to any color with an alpha value of 0 and that did the trick.

Comment: Awesome find! I'm going to add your solution to my comment. Sorry my answer didn't work for you! Nevermind, I see you posted an answer yourself, so I will refrain from adding it~